# I am receiving SSL errors with the PayPal iOS SDK

Tags: ios, paypal

I have an iOS application running the PayPal SDK, oftentimes I receive back "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."

This appears to come from the PayPal SDK itself.  My phone is making other SSL connections fine, and this happens intermittently.

Are there any known issues I should be aware of or known ways to prevent this error?

I also receive "error connecting to server" from the SDK as well, and would love for it not to send up a UIAlertView, but there doesn't seem to be a way to remove that either.

Comment: Which version of the PayPal SDK? Is it the older [MPL](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/) or the newer [PayPal iOS SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK)?

Comment: Looks like it's time to upgrade.  Argh...

Comment: Have exactly the same issue, altough we are not using SDK, but simply redirecting using web. Seems like the SSL connection error is random and rarely happens, but happens.